# Moment.js - Anywhere in the world, use the same Timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I found a couple other posts but they didn't have something specific to what I was looking for.

Here's the scenario:

A user in China (although it could be anywhere in the world) inputs a date time into a field that represents a local time in the U.S.  So even though their local machine might be 1:11 AM 02/15/2018 in Beijing, the user is entering a date in Austin, TX for 11:11 AM 02/14/2018 into the date time field.

This is the string I'm pulling from the input field:
`'2018-02-14T11:11'`

How can I use moment.js to make sure that when I convert `'2018-02-14T11:11'` to UTC, the UTC string *always* reflects Austin time, not Beijing time?  At the end of the day, we won't know which timezone the user is from, but we will always know the entered timezone will be in Central Standard Time.

What seems to be happening with the below is that when I use these to convert to UTC, the dates are still not reflecting CST, or they are offset incorrectly by several hours.

`moment('2018-02-14T11:11').zone("America/Chicago").format()`

`moment('2018-02-14T11:11').tz("America/Chicago").format()`

`moment('2018-02-14T11:11', 'CST').tz("America/Chicago").format()`

`moment('2018-02-14T11:11', "America/Chicago").tz("America/Chicago").format()`

To UTC:

`moment.utc('2018-02-14T11:11').tz("America/Chicago").toISOString()`

I'm definitely missing something.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The whole point to UTC is so that it is a universal time, regardless of the time zone that you are in. In a real-world application, you should be storing UTC in your database, but using a library like Moment.js to DISPLAY the timezone in whatever timezone that you wish for the user to see it in.

Comment: @th3n3wguy - That's sometimes the case, but not always.  In this case the OP appears to be doing exactly that.  They're asking about user input in a local time zone with conversion to UTC.  It's just that the local time zone isn't their own but someone else's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close - you will need the [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) addon, and then it's like this:

```
moment.tz('2018-02-14T11:11', "America/Chicago").utc().format()
```

Let's break that down:

```
// create the moment with a specific time zone
var m = moment.tz('2018-02-14T11:11', "America/Chicago");

// convert to UTC
m.utc();

// format the output
var s = m.format();
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

Just add another scenario that I got:

*Parse `'2018-02-14Z'`, but ignore `'Z'` (UTC), just use local time zone or a specified timezone.*

You can simply remove 'Z' from the string or do these:

`moment('2018-02-14Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` will ignore 'Z' or any unmatched characters.

`moment.tz('2018-02-14Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'America/Chicago')` will use the given timezone.

Of course, you should not do this in the first place. A correct timezone should be used.